# How to disable CKEditor 4.x Spellchecker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am able to disable scayt by using

```
config.removePlugins ='scayt';
```

But how do I disable the spell checker completely.

I have tried both settings below but they dont work.

```
config.removePlugins ='spellchecker';
config.removeButtons ='spellchecker';
```

I have also tried `config.disableNativeSpellChecker = true`
 but didnt work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try this:

   ```
   CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins='scayt,wsc'
   ```
2. Or just remove `spellchecker` toolbar group from `config.js`.